# incompatible type error: JTextField cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtextfield

I'm new to Java coding.

Now I'm trying to save my data to Oracle 18c database coded with JDK 12.0.2 using Apache Netbeans 11.1 IDE.

But when it get compiled the following error comes.

```
Incompatible types: javax.swing.JTextField 
    cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Please guide me in this regard

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking code-related questions, it helps if the community can see a sample of your code. Would you edit your post and add your code to the end..? I'm not a Java expert, but given the wording of the error message, it sounds to me like something is trying to access the JTextField as an object, rather than its `.Text` or `.Value` property. Or perhaps the `.ToString` or an equivalent function needs to be used somewhere..?

Comment: *"I'm new to Java coding. Now I'm trying to save my data to Oracle 18c database coded with JDK 12.0.2 using Apache Netbeans 11.1 IDE."* Solving compiler errors is Java 101, while writing a GUI based app. that accesses a DB is Java 968. (You've likely bitten more than you can chew.)

Answer (score 0):

> "Incompatible types: javax.swing.JTextField cannot be converted to java.lang.String"

You can't just randomly convert an Object from one type to another.

In this case you want to get the text that is being displayed in the `JTextField`.

Your code should be something like:

```
 String text = textField.getText();
```